# Why does empathy show a transparent video preview and then crash?

Tags: video, empathy

When I try to use empathy video chat, no matter what settings I use, it shows a transparent preview, then the video window closes (crashes) I've not gotten any relevant output from the commandline, so I'm not sure what to do.

If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it greatly!

Update: Still happens on 11.04, I'm getting nowhere in fixing it. Anyone wanna help? Do I need to start a bounty???????

Comment: Roland, What version of Ubuntu are you using?
Are you up-to-date on updates? I'm seeing the same behavior here. However, when I try a second time, the window launches and I see video. -Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)
-Empathy 2.32.1

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg: I have to test and see since I upgraded to 11.10.

Comment: @RolandTaylor: So you're still experiencing the issue. Hmm...

Comment: @jrg nope, it's fixed in 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of Empathy (11.10) the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MSN, simply because it is the most popular. It is a known fact by the Empathy developers that video does not work with the MSN protocol. I quote from there official site:

"**Audio and Video calls**

*Does Empathy support audio and video chat?*

Yes. Empathy should be compatible with any client which implement Jingle and supports ICE and the corresponding XEPs properly.

*For which protocols does Empathy support audio and video chat?*

Currently for SIP/XMPP/Gtalk. MSN support is currently broken due to change Microsoft has done to their server."

For more information on this issue and support for other protocols, visit http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ

Comment: sorry but I am not using msn. I have tried that in the past, but quite honestly I'm waiting on emesene to pick up support for msn video. It's XMPP (Jingle) that I'm using, but even test calls do it :(